# What causes electronic shutter to be permanently selected on an FZ300?

Tags: flash, shutter

I have a Lumix DMC-FZ300, my silent mode is off. The flash and shutter type are both grayed out and my shutter type is stuck on electronic shutter so my flash won't work. How do I make it so neither are grayed out?

Comment: What mode are you in? If you're in iAuto the camera takes control. Try it in Program, Aperture or Shutter Preferred

Answer (score 3):

*4K Photo Mode* forces the shutter to electronic. In any case, the flash simply cannot keep up with 30 FPS shooting.

The 60 FPS Burst mode which captures images at 60 FPS also forces the shutter to electronic.

Should none of these apply, Resetting the camera is a decent option. You will have to set it up again but that will make you figure the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a separate setting to control the shutter type.

Menu > Rec > Shutter Type

Below is a link to the page in the user-manual, in case you would like more information.

https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1048484/Panasonic-Lumix-Dmc-Fz300.html?page=159

Answer (score 1):

The camera will not access certain functions when the current mode is incompatible. The pop-up flash needs a manual shutter, not the electronic shutter. But manual shutter also needs '**Silent Mode**' to be '**OFF**'.

So, to get the flash working:

1. turn Silent Mode to 'OFF' (in the Custom Settings tab)
2. change Shutter Type to 'AUTO' or 'MSSHTR' (in the Rec Settings tab)
3. pop up the flash and shoot.

Note that the lens hood partially obscures the pop-up flash, so it will need to be removed to get a proper photo.

Other modes may also render the flash and/or manual shutter inoperable/inaccessible.

Comment: OP stated: "silent mode is off".